# mysql timestamp selecting older records

Tags: php, mysql

I have column where i save timestamp of records and I wants to delete X days older records from my database but I do not wants to delete records which has default value of "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

I tried this query to first select records but it is selecting almost all records and records with default vaule as well.

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE 'Accestime' != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND 'Accestime' < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-60,NOW())
```

Kindly can someone guide what I am doing wrong above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So the records with Accestime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' are getting deleted in this query?

Comment: sorry i am just using SELECT to select all records first, so yea they are also being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your sample query, you are using a literal instead of a column as your date field.

To clarify, 'Accestime' is not the same as `Accestime``. Notice one uses backticks, and the other uses single quotes, so basically you are using a literal string and comparing it to date data. Also, I think you meant to select dates that are *less than* 60 days ago, not greater than. Try something more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE `Accestime` != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND `Accestime` < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-60,NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusing ticks and single quotation marks -- STOP USING TICKS!!!
I do a lot of sql in my career, I have never needed to use ticks. So I very much doubt that any sql server requires the ticks presently.

You are having problems because you are using ticks. If fact, why not use double quotes and ignore the error likely situations of ticks and single quotes.

I know this is not necessary, but good habits save time and headaches.

```
DELETE * FROM file WHERE Accestime != "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
AND Accestime < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-60,NOW())
```